# Why won't background-image display in css?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have a header to which I'm trying to apply a background texture via image file. The html, css and image files are all in the same directory. This is the html:

```
<body>
<div id=header>
  <div id=picture>
    <img=src=picture.jpeg alt="Profile" align="right" width="180" height="180"/>
  </div>
  <div id=caption>
    <h1>BannerText</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is the external style sheet code:

```
#header
{
  background= url('texture.png');
  width:98%;
}
```

The texture image does not appear. If I use it with the background attribute of the original body tag, that is,

```
<body background="texture.png">
```

that does work. That tells me it isn't a problem with the url, and all three files are in the same folder so the relative paths are the same in both the html and css files. Why isn't the texture image showing up as the background to the header div?

Comment: For a start, although this may be a typo, in your top section is should be `<img src="picture.jpeg" alt.....`

Comment: is the external sheet in the same directory as your page? The file `texture.png` will be pulled from whichever directory your style sheet is in, since you have not specified a directory - also what fakeheal said.

Answer (score 3):

It's `background: url('texture.png');`, not `background= url('texture.png');`.

Also

`<img src="picture.jpeg" alt="Profile" align="right" width="180" height="180"/>`

Not

`<img=src=picture.jpeg alt="Profile" align="right" width="180" height="180"/>`

And it's better to wrap attributes values in quotes. Right - `<div id="picture">`,

bad - `<div id=picture>`

Comment: Also, make sure the root path is correct to the image resource.

Comment: @Netizen, yeah, it's cool (also) to use Chrome's developer tool (or a tool like this on another browser) and check out the console. It give's you 404 errors, if an external file (image,css,js) is not found or properly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `<img=src=picture.jpeg
alt="Profile" align="right"
width="180" height="180"/>` to `<img=src=picture.jpeg
alt="Profile" align="right"
width="180" height="180"/>` and in your css should be `{background: url('urimageurl.jpg');`. Make sure the path/ route (e.g http://yourcsspath.come/css/it.css is not going to correspond with ../yourimg.png because it's not the path of route domain!) . Thanks